# What is the most efficient way to compare values of type "object"

Tags: c#, performance, object, compare

I have a method that needs to compare 2 parameters of type `object`. These parameters may be of any type (*e.g.* `string`, `int`, `uint`, `bool`, … `int[]`, `byte[]`, *etc.*) **but the values to compare are always of same type (eg. We either compare an int to an int or an int[] with an int[] value, etc)**.
What is the best and most efficient way to do this in C#?
Here is what I have tried (but it is not working for arrays):

```
public bool CompareParameterValue(string paramName, object value) 
{
  // Note that value and p.value as assumed to be of same type within this function
  bool wasModified = false;
  var p = Parameters.GetParameter(paramName);

  if ((p.value != null) && !p.value.Equals(value)) 
  {
    p.value = value;
    p.state = "Modified";
    wasModified = true;
  }
  return wasModified;
}
```

Please note that efficiency is the key.

Comment: If efficiency is key, why are you using `object` in the first place?

Comment: Have no choice but using object (I have modified the function so that you can see better what I am trying to do). Values can be of any type as the system generates values of any type.  
I have highlighted performance, because people always go for the easy way rather than the performing way.

Comment: Arrays are reference types and do not implement structural equality

Comment: @DavidG, you are making it hard to keep simple :-)  Should make more sense now.

Comment: Your question keeps fundamentally changing, it's impossible to answer now.

Comment: Well, I try to keep it simple, but you keep on asking more details :-) The question did not change. Trying to compare 2 values that can be of any type. thanks

Comment: Impossible to achieve for "any type" if that type doesn't implement `object.Equals()` the way that you want (e.g. Array types). You might write code to handle specific types, but you can't write it for "any type". For example, how would you expect to compare two instances of `TextBox`? Do you expect to include the `Handle` property?

Comment: I understand, it would be difficult. Lets focus on generic types + arrays. Should I implement IEquatable for array types then?

Comment: Looking at that code, efficiency is the least of your problems. `int[]` is not the only thing that's going to fail there. If you take this `object` parameter approach, you are going to get burnt. What good is an efficient program if it is incorrect?

Comment: Why do you say that? I did not choose to use the object type. But I don't see how else considering parameter values can be of many different types. Any better suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the subset of types that are either of a type that properly implements `object.Equals()`, or that implements `IEnumerable`  for a sequence of a type that properly implements `object.Equals` (such as `List<string>` or `int[]` or `IEnumerable<double>`):

```
public static bool ObjectsEqual(object lhs, object rhs)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(lhs, rhs))
        return true;

    if (lhs == null)
        return false;

    if (rhs == null)
        return false;

    if (lhs.GetType() != rhs.GetType())
        return false;

    if (lhs is IEnumerable seq1 && rhs is IEnumerable seq2)
        return seq1.Cast<object>().SequenceEqual(seq2.Cast<object>());

    return lhs.Equals(rhs);
}
```

Then you can call that in your `CompareParameterValue()` method instead of calling `p.value.Equals(value)`, i.e.:

```
if (ObjectsEqual(p.value, value))
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems the source code already implements something similar. ReferenceEquals is used pretty much as you have described it, but for some reasons when I compare 2 arrays it returns false even when they are the same. Is ReferenceEquals only for non array types?

Comment: For instance, this does not work: https://rextester.com/QAP22756.
Probably comparing that objects are the same rather than containing the same value?

Comment: @stackMeUp You are misreading the code I posted. The `ReferenceEquals()` is an optimisation so that it returns `true` immediately if the two objects are the same object. Otherwise, it will continue on to call `SequenceEqual()` if the objects implement `IEnumerable`, and *that* will return `true` if the two sequences are the same.

Comment: Do you think you could share a good example that implement IEnumerable. I cannot make sense of it. Or rather SequenceEqual() implementation.

Comment: [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual()` is documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.8) and [here is its implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,63644a881e976b52,references).

Answer (score 0):

Make a interface and then use your `obj as IYourInterface`.
If `obj` doesnt implement `IYourInterface` it will return null so you can check for that, an implementation could look like so:

```
public interface IYourInterface
{
   public int value;
   public string modified;
}

public static void Equals(object obj1, object obj2)
{
   var eq1 = obj1 as IYourInterface;
   var eq2 = obj2 as IYourInterface;
   //check if both objects implement the interface
   if(eq1 == null || eq2 == null)
   {
      return false;
   }
   else
   {
      return /*your checks*/
   }
}
```

Remember to implement the IEquatable interface explicitly since thats what you're doing here. If you cant use an interface you probably have a underling issue in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into IEquatable as you suggested

Comment: Better to use generics with a type constraint if you do this, however, this doesn't handle several situations so is not enough.